# How to dynamically import a module or a resource using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a single page web application that is built using webpack, but dynamic import of resources just doesn't work in webpack because it replaces the original relative path in the generated code with "./".

For example:
I have a few *.html files in the "./resources" subfolder and want to import them dynamically.
So I do something like this:

```
const s = "file_name";
import( `./resources/${s}.html` ).then( (file)=>console.log( file.default ) );
```

Pretty simple and nearly exactly as it's [described](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) in webpack's documentation.
But when the code is executed, I just get a runtime error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './file_name.html'

As you can see, the module's path disappeared and has been replaced with "./".
And when I see webpacks's "--stats-modules-space" output I see the next:

> ```
> modules by path ./src/resources/ 320 bytes
>      ./src/resources/ lazy ^\.\/file_name.*\.html$ namespace object 160 bytes [built] 
> [code generated]
> ```

The imported resource is processed and included into the bundle, but the path to the resource is replaced with "./"
And if I change the code to:

```
import( `./resources/file_name.html` ).then( (file)=>console.log( file.default ) );
```

Everything works as expected.

Why does webpack replace the real path with "./" and how can dynamic import be used in practice? The documentation and examples there seem pretty clear and simple regarding this.

**Added:**
If there is no file extension specified and the imported files are not resources but JS-modules (the files themselves have a ".js" extensions) then everything works as expected.
I mean that everything is OK if the file is "./resources/file_name.js" and the code is:

> ```
> const s = "file_name";
> import( `./resources/${s}` ).then( (file)=>console.log( file.default ) );
> ```

Everything is perfect. And yes, I have correct rules for ".html" files being imported and it doesn't work if I specify asset type with resource queries or even with the good old loader ("raw-loader!...").

**Added:**
As I already investigated, the relative dynamic import works only for "real" js-modules and seems broken for any resources.
Now I am a bit worried that I can't find any bug report for that.

**Added:**
Okay. As I see, webpack just assumes that all dynamically imported resources with variable parts in their compile-time paths are ALWAYS located at the public path regardless of what kind of asset they are and even if it processes the files themselves correctly and includes them into the bundle. The problem is that it changes path in the generated code (replaces with "./") but doesn't change it in the runtime module list, so the module list will still contain the correct initial path and the module cannot be found runtime.
And wepback does that only for dynamic imports with variable path parts. If the path is a constant or the module is a "regular" JS-module (not an asset), everything works as expected. Looks pretty insane and feels like a huge bug.

**The result:**
Ok. So I spent 8 hours digging in and found a huge bug in the current version of webpack 5. The dynamic import with variable path is completely broken. The problem is that if there is a variable path, webpack considers this import as having no file extension and thus uses executes resolution for every file then possibly may be imported before any other test. As the result, only ".js" and ".ts" and other "real" JS-modules can be imported. I traced the whole thing in the webpack and 100% sure in my conclusions.
I don't know for how long such a big bug exists and why it's not fixed yet.
I will probably create a bug and report when I find time for that.

Comment: Do `./resources/file_name.html` and `./resources/filename.html` exist in your project? Webpack will import all files with `./resources/*.html`. If `./resources/file_name.html` doesn't exist at build time, it can't be "imported" at runtime.

Comment: I believe you made a typo in `const s = "file_name";`  since you said `import( \`./resources/filename.htm\l` )` worked. Note the underscore.

Comment: How do you import an HTML file and what is its defaut export?

Comment: The files exist and the typo was in the question test. I fixed the question text. I also noticed that webpack changes the path only if file extension is specified in the import string. I mean that if I import a js module with ".js" extension and "${s}" is the last thing in the string everything works as expected.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] on your computer and copy and paste it. It doesn't make sense to debug your problem when your question contains different typos. The variable in the last snippet doesn't contain an extension.

Comment: Yeah. Probably I'll do that. The minmal example for webpack seems pretty big. As I already investigated, relative dynamic import works only for real JS-modules and not for any resources.

Comment: Ok. So I spent 8 hours digging in and found a huge bug in the current version of webpack 5. The dynamic import with variable path is completely broken. The problem is that if there is a variable path, webpack considers this import as having no file extension and thus uses executes resolution for every file then possibly may be imported before any other test. As the result, only ".js" and ".ts" and other "real" JS-modules can be imported. I traced the whole thing in the webpack and 100% sure in my conclusions.

Comment: I will probably create a bug report when I have time for that. And think that I will delete the question in a while because it's just a bug webpack not an actual question.

Comment: @Sap, did you end up creating an issue on webpack's Github? If not, why not?

Comment: @judah-meek No, I did not make a bug report.

Firstly, when I investigated the problem, I found several related bug reports that have not been fixed for a long time and seem not to be fixed in the future. After reading the discussions, I had a strong impression that the webpack authors are not going to fix the issue because it is not important, as they think users should use this feature to import source code only. Why? Because that's what the authors use it for.

And secondly, I'm in a rather difficult life situation, as a result of which I don't have time and desire to do JS.